# Gamemaker display orientation detection

Tags: game-maker, screen, orientation

I am making a game that needs to detect when the device gets turned over in landscape mode to landscape-flipped to change some game mechanics when the player does so. The project is already set to work only in those two orientations.

I am using an object instantiated in the room with the following code in Step :

```
show_debug_message("Orientation : " + string(display_get_orientation()));
```

But I always get the same input - either "landscape" or "landscape-flipped" and it doesn't seems to change the output in runtime, although if I press the power button on the phone and the game goes in pause, if I flip the phone and I return to the game I get the opposite status, but it keeps repeating itself, as it could not read the real orientation of the phone.

Anyone has faced this problem before?

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah i have faced this problem many times, it was something that i left and came back to. i just set Orientation to Landscape in global game settings. But that did lock it to landscape mode.

Comment: What platform? P.S. When you do `show_debug_message("Orientation : " + display_get_orientation());` there must be error because you tried add a number to string.

Comment: Ryanwhite - I set the project to work in Landscape and Landscape-flipped in the Global Game Settings options for Android. 
@Dmi7ry The platform I am targeting is Android, and you're right, I got null in my output, with the above code, as I forgot to put a string(display_get_orientation()) there :) . The thing is that I always get the same value ( 2 ) .

Comment: What GMS version you used? And what reason for check orientation?

Comment: @Dmi7ry I am using GMS 1.4.1763 (r41504) - The thing is that I want to make some objects game mechanics change when I change orientation, like making objects appear or dissapear.

Comment: I used change orientation lot time ago and don't remember details. But I used it only once. Now I always see is window resized or not, like this: 
`if window_get_width() != surface_get_width(application_surface)
or window_get_height() != surface_get_height(application_surface)
{
    event_user(1);
}`
  
And inside the user event I do all what I want (change GUI layout, etc)

Comment: @Dmi7ry That looks like a nice solutions to compare from portrait to landscape. In my case I just found that this is a bug in the gamemaker platform that hasn't been fixed yet: http://bugs.yoyogames.com/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=15291 I wonder if anyone has found a work around to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different options I finally achieved the result I wanted using the get_tilt_x() function, so:

```
if ((os_type == os_android) || (os_type == os_ios) || (os_type == os_tizen))
{
    show_debug_message("Mobile device detected" + string(orientation));    

    //this always prints the same orientation:   
    show_debug_message("Orientation : " + string(display_get_orientation())); 

    //this is how I solved it:
    if (device_get_tilt_x()<0)
    {
        //flipped state 
        show_debug_message("X: " + string(device_get_tilt_x()));
        show_debug_message("ORIENTATION FLIPPED");
        //do something in flipped state 
    }
    else if (device_get_tilt_x()>=0)
    {
        //normal state
        show_debug_message("X: " + string(device_get_tilt_x()));
        show_debug_message("ORIENTATION NORMAL");
        //do something in normal state 
    }

}
```

Special thanks to Dmi7ry for his advice!

Cheers!